# *ngIf not being evaluated

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular7

I've been trying to make reusable **CRUD Table Component** in **Angular 7**, using **Angular Material**, where i can pass any array of data objects and the table renders the data.

In that Table component i am also passing array of links in pair with column name i want to attach link to, example:

**redirectionLinks = [ {link: '/students', column: 'name} ... ]**

**TableComponent:**

template:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataList | filterByName:searchValue" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columnList; let i = index;" matColumnDef="{{column}}">

    <ng-container *ngIf="column!=='Delete' && column!=='Edit'">

      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>

      <ng-container *ngFor="let linkObj of redirectionLinks;let j = index;">

        <ng-container *ngIf="column === linkObj.column;">
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" [routerLink]="[linkObj.link, item.id]" class="td-hoverable"> {{item[objKeys[i]]}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container *ngIf="column !== linkObj.column;">
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item[objKeys[i]]}} </td>
        </ng-container>



      </ng-container>

    </ng-container>




    <ng-container *ngIf="column=='Delete'">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> <button mat-button color="error" (click)="deleteItem(item)">Delete</button></td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="column=='Edit'">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Edit </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="editItem(item)">Edit</button> </td>
    </ng-container>




  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnList"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let item; columns: columnList;"></tr>


</table>
```

**TableComponent**:
logic:

```
@Input() dataList;
@Input() searchValue: string;
@Input() columnList;
@Input() redirectionLinks;

@Output() emitDeleteEvent = new EventEmitter();
@Output() emitEditEvent = new EventEmitter();

objKeys = [];

console = console;

ngOnInit(): void {

    // since every object has same props we use the first one -> [0]
    this.objKeys = Object.keys(this.dataList[0]);

    // add edit and delete cols
    this.columnList.push('Delete');
    this.columnList.push('Edit');




}


deleteItem(item) {
    this.emitDeleteEvent.emit(item);
}

editItem(item) {
    this.emitEditEvent.emit(item);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("im destroyed");
}
```

**StudentsPageComponent(parent)**

template:

```
<h2 class="centered-header">Students</
    <app-search (searchEvent)="getSearchValue($event)"></app-search>
    <app-table-crud
       (emitDeleteEvent)="deleteStudent($event)"
       (emitEditEvent)="editStudent($event)"
       [dataList]="students"
       [columnList]="tableColumns"
       [searchValue]="searchValue"
       [redirectionLinks]="redirectionLinks"
    ></app-table-crud>
```

**Logic**:

```
export class StudentsPageComponent {

students = [
    { id: '1', name: 'Stefanos Lalic', billAccount: '15123512', accountBalance: '$423.00' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Anastasia Lalic', billAccount: '51231252', accountBalance: '$1423.00' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Olivia Lalic', billAccount: '31515231', accountBalance: '$5122.00'}
];

tableColumns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Bill Acc', 'Balance'];

redirectionLinks = [
    {link: '/billAccount', column: 'Bill Acc'},
    {link: '/student', column: 'Name'}
];

searchValue: string;


getSearchValue(searchValue) {
    this.searchValue = searchValue;
}

deleteStudent(student) {
    console.log(student);
}

editStudent(student) {
    console.log(student);
}
```

}

[This is how it looks rendered, keep in mind that only Bill Acc links are rendered, while /student link is being ignored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jetOK.png)

Comment: Could you be more specific as to which ngIf looks like it is not working? Is it this one: `*ngIf="column === linkObj.column;"`? If you add `{{ column }}` and `{{ linkObj.column }}` to display immediately before the `ngIf`, are you getting the values? Do they exactly match?

Comment: @DeborahK Yes, it is `*ngIf="column === linkObj.column;` 
If i do `{{ column }} {{ linkObj.column }}` instead of `{{item[objKeys[i]]}}` it prints the first element's column name of the list : `redirectionLinks = [ {link: '/bill', column: 'Bill Acc}, {link: '/students', column: 'name} ,    ... ] `
It seems like it the second *ngFor loop never executes, it always hangs on the first element and hence is always evaluating only first element of the list, have a look:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AVy8PYO554pouyjHTWANWXb1z5yW2Llh

Comment: @DeborahK on the other hand, if i do: 
`{{console.log(column, linkObj.column, column == linkObj.column)}}` right after evaluating:
`*ngIf="column === linkObj.column` it prints the following in the console:
Name Name true
Bill Acc Bill Acc true
Name Name true
Bill Acc Bill Acc true ... (8x each) , weird behaviour isn't it?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x5qhWMtmVR30NxE6gTj-wtCxyCbCVfPa

Comment: This is simplified working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tseo1f?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

I was using orange color to indicate the flaw, notice how it evaluates only first link and ignores the second one, try to change the order of links in table component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a function inside my Table component:

```
hasLink(column) {
  return this.redirectionLinks.some(element => 
      element.column === column
  )
}
```

and instead of iterating inside the template with *ngFor i simply used:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="hasLink(column); then with_link else without_link">

    </ng-container>
```